# Running "module.exports = function(foo){...}" in Node vm2

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-vm2

I'm new to Node and the virtual machine [vm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2). In the documentation for the latter, it gives an example of its usage:

```
let functionInSandbox = vm.run("module.exports = function(who) { console.log('hello '+ who); }");
functionInSandbox('world');
```

**Question: what is this actually doing?**

Firstly, why is `module.exports` used here at all? Ie, why not omit it as below?

```
let functionInSandbox = vm.run("function(who) { console.log('hello '+ who); }");
functionInSandbox('world');
```

Secondly, another way of looking at it: in regular node programming, it is beginner's knowledge that `require(inc)` is used in one file to assign to a variable, what, in another file (chosen by `inc`), is assigned to `module.exports`. How is that different to the above usage with `vm2`?

Specifically: is `require(...)` being implicitly called in the above? How could multiple modules be defined (as above) and referred to, within one sandbox?

It's hard to know what questions to even ask - really I'm just hoping for an explanation of ways in which `module.exports` can be used with `vm2` in ways that differ to regular node programming, highlighting differences.